# Convert UNIX Epoch to Datetime depending on culture

Tags: c#, cultureinfo

I'm developing a method that will receive UNIX timestamp and culture:

```
public DateTime unixEpochToDateTime(long unixTimeStamp, string culture) {
    ...
}
```

Call example:

```
DateTime t = unixEpochToDateTime(1478181983, "es-ES");
```

I need convert this UTC time between many cultures, without using **TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone** because this method will be run in server and the server culture is allways the same.

For example, if two user request my method in EE.UU and in Great Britain, I get the same UTC?

I'm very confused.

Comment: As am I by your question (at the moment). You have a unix timestamp, can I assume that the timestamp is also from UTC or is there an offset stored with this timestamp?

Comment: @Igor Timestamp is UTC. Thanks!

Comment: Then why not create the `DateTime` instance in utc? Also the datetime has a property for [Kind](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shx7s921(v=vs.110).aspx) that you can set which will allow you to specify UTC (there is also an overload in the constructor where you can set it as well). See static method `DateTime.SpecifyKind`.

Comment: I'm trying this: 

`DateTime datetime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            datetime = datetime.AddSeconds(unixTimeStamp)`

But allways return time different of my culture (one hour less)

Comment: Not sure what your local offset is but to get your local time you can use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tolocaltime(v=vs.110).aspx. `var mylocal = datetime.ToLocalTime();`

Comment: @Igor But.... this ToLocalTime() depends on current culture... user that invoke this method will be passing unix epoch and her culture

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can try [nodatime](http://nodatime.org/). It has many usefull methods.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved...

If .NET does not provide a mechanism is because it is impossible to determine the time difference UTC based on culture.

Basically because a culture can have different time zones.

Culture "es-ES" for example, has 2 zones: GTM + 0 for Canary Islands and UTC + 1 for Iberian Peninsula.